# Expressing $P$ in terms of elementary symmetric polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

We know that $Q(t_1, t_2, \cdots, t_n)=\prod_{i=1}^n(t_i-1)=\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^{n-i}s_i$, where $s_i$ is the $i$-th elementary symmetric polynomial in $t_1, \cdots, t_n$. Let $P(t_1, t_2, \cdots, t_n)=\prod_{1\leq i<j\leq n}(t_it_j-1)$. What is the polynomial $R(s_1, \cdots, s_n)$ such that $P(t_1, t_2, \cdots, t_n)=R(s_1, s_2, \cdots, s_n)$? I ask this because I would like to know, given a polynomial equation $x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0=0$ with roots $\{\alpha_i\}_{i=1}^n$, what is the monic polynomial equation with roots $\{\alpha_i\alpha_j\}_{1\leq i<j\leq n}$?